# Adding data to a particular table in CoreData in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am using CoreData in my project and I am successfully able to save data in my tables and display. I am also able to update the existing Data. but I am not able to add a new data to a particular table.[image]

The table relation is WorkOrderData--> one to many with WorkOrderTaskAsset  and WorkOrderTaskAsset --> one to many with condition.

If I have to add a condition Object on some button click. I am not getting how to add it. I tried to create a Condition Object  and add it. But I am getting error
.Condition setLabel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000077540'

```
func saveDataInCoreData(jsonArray : NSArray)  {
    for orders in jsonArray{

        let WorkOrderDataClassName:String = String(describing: WorkOrderData.self)
        let workOrderData:WorkOrderData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: WorkOrderDataClassName, into: DatabaseController.getContext()) as! WorkOrderData

        let ContractorClassName:String = String(describing: Contractor.self)
        let contractor:Contractor = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: ContractorClassName, into: DatabaseController.getContext()) as! Contractor

        let StatusClassName:String = String(describing: Status.self)
        let status:Status = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: StatusClassName, into: DatabaseController.getContext()) as! Status





        let order = orders as! NSDictionary

        // Work Order Parsing
        workOrderData.workOrderNo = order["workOrderNo"]! as? String
        if order["description"] != nil {
        workOrderData.descriptin = order["description"]! as? String
        }

        if order["comments"] != nil {
            workOrderData.comments = order["comments"]! as? String

        }

        let desCodeId = order["descriptionCodeID"]! as? Int
        if desCodeId != nil {
            workOrderData.descriptionCodeID = Int16(UInt16(desCodeId!))
        }

        if order["definition"] != nil {
            workOrderData.definition = order["definition"]! as? String

        }

        let priortyID = order["priorityID"]! as? Int
        if priortyID != nil {
            workOrderData.priorityID = Int16(UInt16(desCodeId!))
        }

        let numbrOfAssets = order["numberofAssests"]! as? Int
        if numbrOfAssets != nil {
            workOrderData.numberofAssests = Int16(UInt16(numbrOfAssets!))
        }



        if order["generatedDateTime"] != nil {
            workOrderData.generatedDateTime = (order["generatedDateTime"]! as? Double)!
        }
        if order["initiatedBy"] != nil {
            workOrderData.initiatedBy = order["initiatedBy"]! as? String
        }
        if order["generatedBy"] != nil {
            workOrderData.generatedBy = order["generatedBy"]! as? String
        }

        if order["issueDate"] != nil {
            workOrderData.issueDate = (order["issueDate"]! as? Double)!
        }

        if order["finishDate"] != nil {
         workOrderData.finishDate = (order["finishDate"]! as? Double)!
        }



        if order["statusID"] != nil {
            let statsID = order["statusID"]! as? Int
            workOrderData.statusID = Int16(UInt16(statsID!))
        }


        if order["assigneeID"] != nil {
            let assigneID = order["assigneeID"]! as? Int
            workOrderData.assigneeID = Int16(UInt16(assigneID!))
        }



        if order["updateDate"] != nil {
            let updatDate = order["updateDate"]! as? Double
            workOrderData.updateDate = updatDate!
        }
        if order["startDate"] != nil {
            workOrderData.startDate = (order["startDate"]! as? Double)!
        }
        if order["proceedDate"] != nil {
            workOrderData.proceedDate = (order["proceedDate"]! as? Double)!
        }

        if order["createDate"] != nil {
            workOrderData.createDate = (order["createDate"]! as? Double)!

        }


        if order["inclementDays"] != nil {
            let inclemntDays = order["inclementDays"]! as? Int
            workOrderData.inclementDays = Int16(UInt16(inclemntDays!))
        }


        if order["totalHydrantsPainted"] != nil {
            let totalHydrantPainted = order["totalHydrantsPainted"]! as? Int
            workOrderData.totalHydrantsPainted = Int16(UInt16(totalHydrantPainted!))
        }


        if order["totalHydrantsNotPainted"] != nil {
            let totalHydrantNotPainted = order["totalHydrantsNotPainted"]! as? Int
            workOrderData.totalHydrantsNotPainted = Int16(UInt16(totalHydrantNotPainted!))
        }


        if order["contractorId"] != nil {
            let contractrId = order["contractorId"]! as? Int
            workOrderData.contractorId = Int16(UInt16(contractrId!))
        }

        // Contractor Started

        let contractorDict = order["contractor"]! as? NSDictionary


        if contractorDict?["id"] != nil {
            let contrctrId = contractorDict?["id"]! as? Int
            contractor.id = Int16(UInt16(contrctrId!))
        }
        contractor.name = contractorDict?["name"]! as? String
        contractor.email = contractorDict?["email"]! as? String
        contractor.label = contractorDict?["label"]! as? String
        contractor.purchaseOrderNumber = contractorDict?["purchaseOrderNumber"]! as? String
        contractor.vendorId = contractorDict?["vendorId"]! as? String
        workOrderData.contractor = contractor

        if order["status"] != nil {
            let statusDict = order["status"]! as? NSDictionary

            let statusId = statusDict?["id"]! as? Int
            if statusId != nil {
                status.id = Int16(UInt16(statusId!))
            }
            status.label = statusDict?["label"]! as? String
            status.descriptin = statusDict?["description"]! as? String
            status.rule = statusDict?["rule"]! as? String

            workOrderData.status = status
        }


        // Inclement Work Order  Started

        if order["workOrderInclementWeatherDates"]  != nil {
            let workOrderInclementWeatherDate = order["workOrderInclementWeatherDates"] as! [NSDictionary]

            if workOrderInclementWeatherDate.count > 0 {
                let setArray = NSMutableArray()
                let set = NSMutableSet()
                for inclementItem in workOrderInclementWeatherDate {

                    let WorkOrderInclementWeatherDatesClassName:String = String(describing: WorkOrderInclementWeatherDates.self)
                    let workOrderInclementWeatherDates:WorkOrderInclementWeatherDates = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: WorkOrderInclementWeatherDatesClassName, into: DatabaseController.getContext()) as! WorkOrderInclementWeatherDates

                    workOrderInclementWeatherDates.createTimeStamp = inclementItem.value(forKey: "createTimeStamp") as! Double
                    workOrderInclementWeatherDates.inclementDate = inclementItem.value(forKey: "inclementDate") as! Double
                    workOrderInclementWeatherDates.workOrderNo = inclementItem.value(forKey: "workOrderNo") as? String

                    setArray.add(workOrderInclementWeatherDates)
                    set.add(workOrderInclementWeatherDates)


                }
                workOrderData.addToWorkOrderInclementWeather(set as NSSet)

            }



        }

        // Task List

        // Inclement Work Order  Started

        if order["workOrderTask"]  != nil {
            let workOrderTaskArray = order["workOrderTask"] as! [NSDictionary]

            if workOrderTaskArray.count > 0 {
                let workOrderSet = NSMutableSet()
                for workOrderItem in workOrderTaskArray {

                    let WorkOrderTaskClassName:String = String(describing: WorkOrderTask.self)
                    let workOrderTask:WorkOrderTask = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: WorkOrderTaskClassName, into: DatabaseController.getContext()) as! WorkOrderTask

                    workOrderTask.woTaskDescription = workOrderItem.value(forKey: "woTaskDescription") as? String

                    workOrderTask.taskStatus = workOrderItem.value(forKey: "taskStatus") as? String
                    if workOrderItem["projectedStartDate"] != nil {
                        workOrderTask.projectedStartDate = workOrderItem.value(forKey: "projectedStartDate") as! Double
                    }
                    if workOrderItem["actualStartDate"] != nil {
                        workOrderTask.actualStartDate = workOrderItem.value(forKey: "actualStartDate") as! Double
                    }


                    if workOrderItem["taskNumber"] != nil {
                        let taskNumber = workOrderItem["taskNumber"]! as? Int
                        workOrderTask.taskNumber = Int16(UInt16(taskNumber!))
                    }

                    if workOrderItem["noOfHydrantsCompleted"] != nil {
                        let noOfHydrantsCompleted = workOrderItem["noOfHydrantsCompleted"]! as? Int
                        workOrderTask.noOfHydrantsCompleted = Int16(UInt16(noOfHydrantsCompleted!))
                    }

                    if workOrderItem["noOfHydrantsPending"] != nil {
                        let noOfHydrantsPending = workOrderItem["noOfHydrantsPending"]! as? Int
                        workOrderTask.noOfHydrantsPending = Int16(UInt16(noOfHydrantsPending!))
                    }

                    workOrderSet.add(workOrderTask)


                }
                workOrderData.addToWorkOrdertask(workOrderSet as NSSet)

            }



        }

        // workOrderTaskAsstDetails

        if order["workOrderTaskAsstDetails"]  != nil {
            let workOrderTaskAsstDetailsDict = order["workOrderTaskAsstDetails"] as! [NSDictionary]

            if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsDict.count > 0 {
                let set = NSMutableSet()
                for workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem in workOrderTaskAsstDetailsDict {

                    let WorkOrderTaskAsstDetailsClassName:String = String(describing: WorkOrderTaskAsstDetails.self)
                    let workOrderTaskAsstDetails:WorkOrderTaskAsstDetails = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: WorkOrderTaskAsstDetailsClassName, into: DatabaseController.getContext()) as! WorkOrderTaskAsstDetails

                    let woTaskAsstId = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["woTaskAsstId"]! as? Int
                    if woTaskAsstId != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.woTaskAsstId = Int16(UInt16(woTaskAsstId!))
                    }

                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.woTaskNo = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem.value(forKey: "woTaskNo") as? String
                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.assetId = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem.value(forKey: "assetId") as? String
                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.descripton = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem.value(forKey: "description") as? String
                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.statusID = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem.value(forKey: "statusID") as? String
                    if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["projectedStartDate"] != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.projectedStartDate = (workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["projectedStartDate"]! as? Double)!

                    }
                    if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["actualStartDate"] != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.actualStartDate = (workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["actualStartDate"]! as? Double)!

                    }
                    if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["projectedCompleteDate"] != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.projectedCompleteDate = (workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["projectedCompleteDate"]! as? Double)!

                    }
                    if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["actualCompleteDate"] != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.actualCompleteDate = (workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["actualCompleteDate"]! as? Double)!

                    }
                    if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["lastPaintedDate"] != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.lastPaintedDate = (workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["lastPaintedDate"]! as? Double)!

                    }
                    if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["workOrderStartDate"] != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.workOrderStartDate = (workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["workOrderStartDate"]! as? Double)!

                    }
                    if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["createDate"] != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.createDate = (workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["createDate"]! as? Double)!

                    }
                    if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["updateDate"] != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.updateDate = (workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["updateDate"]! as? Double)!

                    }
                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.workOrderNumber = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem.value(forKey: "workOrderNumber") as? String
                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.beforePicLatitude = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem.value(forKey: "beforePicLatitude") as? String
                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.beforePicLongitude = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem.value(forKey: "beforePicLongitude") as? String
                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.afterPicLatitude = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem.value(forKey: "afterPicLatitude") as? String
                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.afterPicLongitude = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem.value(forKey: "afterPicLongitude") as? String

                    let transactionType = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["transactionType"]! as? Int
                    if transactionType != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.transactionType = Int16(UInt16(transactionType!))
                    }
                    let assetValid = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["assetValid"]! as? Int
                    if assetValid != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.assetValid = Int16(UInt16(assetValid!))
                    }

                    //Asset
                    let AssetClassName:String = String(describing: Asset.self)
                    let asset:Asset = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: AssetClassName, into: DatabaseController.getContext()) as! Asset

                    let assetDict = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["asset"]! as? NSDictionary
                    asset.descripton = assetDict?["description"]! as? String
                    asset.type = assetDict?["type"]! as? String
                    asset.assetId = assetDict?["assetId"]! as? String
                    if assetDict?["asset200ft"] != nil {
                        asset.asset200ft = assetDict?["asset200ft"]! as? String
                    }


                    if  assetDict?["streetNumber"] != nil{
                        asset.streetNumber = assetDict?["streetNumber"]! as? String
                    }

                    asset.county = assetDict?["county"]! as? String
                    asset.latitude = assetDict?["latitude"]! as? String
                    asset.longitude = assetDict?["longitude"]! as? String
                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.asset = asset

                    //Condition

                        if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["assetConditions"] != nil{
                        let conditionDict = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["assetConditions"] as! [NSDictionary]

                        if conditionDict.count > 0{
                        let conditinSet = NSMutableSet()

                        for assetConditionsDetailsDict in conditionDict {

                        let ConditionClassName:String = String(describing: Condition.self)
                        let condition:Condition = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: ConditionClassName, into: DatabaseController.getContext()) as! Condition

                        let assetConditionItem = assetConditionsDetailsDict["condition"] as! NSDictionary
                        condition.id = assetConditionItem["id"]as? String
                            condition.label = assetConditionItem["label"]as? String
                            condition.rule = assetConditionItem["rule"]as? String
                            condition.descriptin = assetConditionItem["description"]as? String
                            conditinSet.add(condition)


                            }
                            workOrderTaskAsstDetails.addToCondition(conditinSet as NSSet)

                         }
                }
                    set.add(workOrderTaskAsstDetails)



                }
                workOrderData.addToWorkOrderTaskAsstDetails(set as NSSet)

            }



        }

        // assetList


        if order["assetList"]  != nil {
            let workOrderTaskAsstDetailsDict = order["assetList"] as! [NSDictionary]

            if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsDict.count > 0 {
                let set = NSMutableSet()
                for workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem in workOrderTaskAsstDetailsDict {

                    let WorkOrderTaskAsstDetailsClassName:String = String(describing: AssetList.self)
                    let workOrderTaskAsstDetails:AssetList = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: WorkOrderTaskAsstDetailsClassName, into: DatabaseController.getContext()) as! AssetList

                    let woTaskAsstId = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["woTaskAsstId"]! as? Int
                    if woTaskAsstId != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.woTaskAsstId = Int16(UInt16(woTaskAsstId!))
                    }

                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.woTaskNo = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem.value(forKey: "woTaskNo") as? String
                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.assetId = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem.value(forKey: "assetId") as? String
                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.descripton = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem.value(forKey: "description") as? String
                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.statusID = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem.value(forKey: "statusID") as? String
                    if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["projectedStartDate"] != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.projectedStartDate = (workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["projectedStartDate"]! as? Double)!

                    }
                    if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["actualStartDate"] != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.actualStartDate = (workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["actualStartDate"]! as? Double)!

                    }
                    if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["projectedCompleteDate"] != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.projectedCompleteDate = (workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["projectedCompleteDate"]! as? Double)!

                    }
                    if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["actualCompleteDate"] != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.actualCompleteDate = (workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["actualCompleteDate"]! as? Double)!

                    }
                    if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["lastPaintedDate"] != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.lastPaintedDate = (workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["lastPaintedDate"]! as? Double)!

                    }
                    if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["workOrderStartDate"] != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.workOrderStartDate = (workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["workOrderStartDate"]! as? Double)!

                    }
                    if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["createDate"] != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.createDate = (workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["createDate"]! as? Double)!

                    }
                    if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["updateDate"] != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.updateDate = (workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["updateDate"]! as? Double)!

                    }
                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.workOrderNumber = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem.value(forKey: "workOrderNumber") as? String
                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.beforePicLatitude = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem.value(forKey: "beforePicLatitude") as? String
                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.beforePicLongitude = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem.value(forKey: "beforePicLongitude") as? String
                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.afterPicLatitude = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem.value(forKey: "afterPicLatitude") as? String
                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.afterPicLongitude = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem.value(forKey: "afterPicLongitude") as? String

                    let transactionType = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["transactionType"]! as? Int
                    if transactionType != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.transactionType = Int16(UInt16(transactionType!))
                    }
                    let assetValid = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["assetValid"]! as? Int
                    if assetValid != nil {
                        workOrderTaskAsstDetails.assetValid = Int16(UInt16(assetValid!))
                    }

                    //Asset
                    let AssetClassName:String = String(describing: AssetListAsset.self)
                    let asset:AssetListAsset = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: AssetClassName, into: DatabaseController.getContext()) as! AssetListAsset

                    let assetDict = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["asset"]! as? NSDictionary
                    asset.descripton = assetDict?["description"]! as? String
                    asset.type = assetDict?["type"]! as? String
                    asset.assetId = assetDict?["assetId"]! as? String
                    if assetDict?["asset200ft"] != nil {
                        asset.asset200ft = assetDict?["asset200ft"]! as? String
                    }


                    if  assetDict?["streetNumber"] != nil{
                        asset.streetNumber = assetDict?["streetNumber"]! as? String
                    }

                    asset.county = assetDict?["county"]! as? String
                    asset.latitude = assetDict?["latitude"]! as? String
                    asset.longitude = assetDict?["longitude"]! as? String
                    workOrderTaskAsstDetails.assetListAsset = asset

                    //Condition

                    if workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["assetConditions"] != nil{
                        let conditionDict = workOrderTaskAsstDetailsItem["assetConditions"] as! [NSDictionary]

                        if conditionDict.count > 0{
                            let conditinSet = NSMutableSet()

                            for assetConditionsDetailsDict in conditionDict {

                                let ConditionClassName:String = String(describing: AssetListCondition.self)
                                let condition:AssetListCondition = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: ConditionClassName, into: DatabaseController.getContext()) as! AssetListCondition

                                let assetConditionItem = assetConditionsDetailsDict["condition"] as! NSDictionary
                                condition.id = assetConditionItem["id"]as? String
                                condition.label = assetConditionItem["label"]as? String
                                condition.rule = assetConditionItem["rule"]as? String
                                condition.descriptin = assetConditionItem["description"]as? String
                                conditinSet.add(condition)


                            }
                            workOrderTaskAsstDetails.addToAssetListCondition(conditinSet as NSSet)

                        }
                    }
                    set.add(workOrderTaskAsstDetails)



                }
                workOrderData.addToAssetList(set as NSSet)

            }



        }




        DatabaseController.saveContext()





    }
    fetchFrmDB()
}
```

the code include other table also which I have not shown in pic
Please help me.. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you please post the code where you create and try to add your Condition?

Comment: Please read a basic Ray Wenderlich tutorial or watch one of the many great YT tutorials. This is basic stuff you'll have to learn on your own; like we all did. Then if you have a very specific question (this post doesn't give a clue), come back much later.

Comment: @MarcioRomeroPatrnogic  Please  find the code

Comment: I am saving it in my app delegate Class. And I have to add the object  from other class

Comment: conditionDict is supposed to be a dictionary or an array?

Comment: Its a array of dictionary

Comment: What does the stack trace for the exception tell you? It usually shows the calls that are made that lead to the failure and that might help you track down where the issue comes from.

Comment: Hi Abizem. As far as I understand it tells that you cannot set the condition object and assign it to parent object